Redirect port 8080 to a folder with apache
I would like to forward port 8080 to my Test folder. I can also reach this. But the website under port 8080 refers to /css/example.css. If I now call up my website 192.168.200.20/test, the CSS file is not loaded because it is loaded from 192.168.200.20/css/example.css. It should actually load from 192.168.200.20/test/css/example.css.
My Apache2 config currently looks like this:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPass /test/ http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse /test/ http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>

